Why don't we talk about the category of all $\mathsf C$'s with small $\operatorname{Obj}(\mathsf C)$?
Emily Riehl in her Category Theory in Context writes:

To put a lid on things, define $\mathsf{Cat}$ to be the category whose objects are small categories and whose morphisms are functors between them. This category is locally small but not small [...].
The non-small categories [...] are objects of $\mathsf{CAT}$, some category of “large” categories and functors between them. Russell’s paradox suggests that $\mathsf{CAT}$ should not be so large as to contain itself, so we require the objects in $\mathsf{CAT}$ to be locally small categories; the category $\mathsf{CAT}$ defined in this way is not locally small, and so is thus excluded.

This allows one to restrict the "functorial" association that maps any categories $\mathsf{C}$, $\mathsf{D}$, to the functor category $\mathsf{D^C}$, to bona fide functors $\mathsf{Cat}^\text{op}\times \mathsf{Cat}\to\mathsf{Cat}$ and $\mathsf{Cat}^\text{op}\times \mathsf{CAT}\to\mathsf{CAT}$. However, we can easily go one step further as follows.
Define the category $\mathsf{CAt}$ containing categories whose object sets are small. Clearly, $\mathsf{CAt}$'s object set is not small, and thus passes Emily's necessary criterion (sufficient? I am not sure) for it to be a bona fide category. (@varkor had previously answered that such categories are precisely the small $\mathsf{Class}$-enriched categories.) Nevertheless, the usefulness of defining this is showcased by at least the following two (easy) observations:

If $\mathsf C$ has small object set and $\mathsf D$ is locally small, then the functor category $\mathsf{D^C}$ is locally small. Thus we can extend the above functors to another bona fide functor $\mathsf{CAt}^\text{op}\times \mathsf{CAT}\to\mathsf{CAT}$.

(Assume $\mathsf{AC}$ for this point.) If $\mathsf C$ has small object set and $\mathsf D$ is small, then essentially surjective functors $\mathsf{C\to D}$ are precisely the split essentially surjective $\mathsf{C\to D}$. Thus, the same proof of the usual result

A functor fully faithful (not necessarily split) essentially surjective functor $\mathsf{C\to D}$ specifies an equivalence if $\mathsf C$, $\mathsf D$ are small.

sails through even if $\mathsf C$ is large as long as its object set is small.


Question: Despite this, why haven't category theorists talked of $\mathsf{CAt}$? Is there a reason why the stratification using the size of object sets not considered? (The categories $\mathsf{Cat}$ and $\mathsf{CAT}$ arise by considering the size of morphism sets.)

Are there any examples of such categories you actually care about? I don't think anyone particularly cares about e.g. one-object categories with a proper class of endomorphisms.

A category with a small set of objects is small if and only if it is locally small.

@QiaochuYuan Isn't the fact that the same arguments sail through more general situations (even if not immediately finding many use cases) justification enough for caring about the new definition? But then, I guess, not every generalization is the "right" generalization (which I characterize by "saying a lot in fewest words") and to find and appreciate it, I guess one has no other option to first study what's already been done... [goes back to my CatTheo class]

Type theory lends itself well to this kind of generalisation, because the type of categories is parametrised by two universe levels (one for objects, one for hom-sets), and so is the bicategory of categories.

It's a genuinely mildly interesting observation that these constructions work. But for people to actually talk about a concept it needs to satisfy at least one of, as Qiaochu mentioned, the existence of some interesting examples or the proving of some nontrivial theorems. An example of the second case is the property of well-poweredness: it's incredibly rare for a naturally-occurring locally small category to fail to be well-powered (and almost as rare for it to fail to be co-well-powered), but these conditions show up as premises in highly nontrivial theorems, so the concepts get talked about even though relevant examples are artificial. $\mathbf{CAt}$ suffered from both the examples being artificial and the theorems being, I think, rather trivial.
